# Cannot find module within another function/file

Tags: javascript, module, phantomjs, casperjs

I'm running a **casper** project and I have two files:

The code in `main.js` is:

```
var casper = require('casper').create();
var aSecondary = require('./secondary.js');
aSecondary.secondaryRun();
```

The code in `secondary.js` is:

```
function secondaryRun() {
    var aSecondaryCasper = require('casper').create();
}
exports.secondaryRun = secondaryRun;
```

> Error: Cannot find module 'casper'
>           /home/username/phantomjs:/platform/secondary.js:1 in secondaryRun

I don't understand why I can find the **casper** module in `main.js` and not in `secondary.js`.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Fixed this. It's documented at: http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/writing_modules.html

I required this in secondary.js to get it working:

```
var require = patchRequire(require);
```